# I get this error DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm making a ban command for my discord bot and everything's working except for one thing, the embed that the bot is supposed to send to the banned user is not being sent I'm getting a Discord API problem, this problem:

> DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body

Here is my `ban.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'ban',
    description: "This command bans a member!",
    async execute(message, args) {
        const member = message.mentions.users.first();


        if(message.member.roles.cache.has("858091311126806538")) {

        if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
            return message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}**, I do not have perms to ban someone`)
          }
        
        let banReason = args.join(" ").slice(22);
        if (!banReason) {
            banReason = "None"
        }
 
        if (member) {
            const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id);
 
            const Discord = require('discord.js');

            const delay = (msec) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, msec));

            const authoRR = message.author.tag;
            const banEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
 
 
 
                .setColor('#ff0000')
                .setTitle(`You are banned from Anime Club!`)
                .setAuthor(`${authoRR}`, `${message.author.displayAvatarURL()}`)
                .setThumbnail(member.displayAvatarURL())

                .addFields(
                    { name: 'Banned User:', value: `${memberTarget}` },
                    { name: 'Ban Reason:', value: `${banReason}` },
                    { name: ' ', value: `You were **banned** from Anime Club,
                    please do not try to rejoin the server or beg the owner to unban you`}
                )
                .setTimestamp()
            message.mentions.users.first().send(banEmbed);
            await delay(100);
            memberTarget.ban({
                reason: banReason
            })
 
            const Author = message.author;

            const BanEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
 
                .setColor('#ff0000')
                .setTitle(`User has been banned!`)
                .setThumbnail(member.displayAvatarURL())

                .addFields(
                    { name: 'Banned User:', value: `${memberTarget}` },
                    { name: 'Ban Reason:', value: `${banReason}` },
                    { name: 'Banned by:', value: `${Author}` },
                )
 
            message.channel.send(BanEmbed);

        } else {
            return message.reply(`Please mention a member!`);
        
        }
        
      } else return message.reply(`You must be an administrator to unban a member`)
    }
}
```

Can anyone help? I really don't understand this problem.

Comment: Please convert this code into a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You should only include the part that has the error, along with some declarations you might need to put in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `name` property of [`EmbedFieldData`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/EmbedFieldData) cannot be empty. Discord considers a field name empty if it consists only of [whitespace characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character). If you want to leave the content visibly empty, you could try something like this.

```js
{
    name: '** **',
    value: `You were **banned** from Anime Club,
            please do not try to rejoin the server or beg the owner to unban you`
}
```